# Rspec not generating *_spec.rb file in Rails 4 beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have already install rspec-rails gem. When I run `rails g model movie showtime_date:date showtime_time:time` I think, I should get

```
invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130604010556_create_movies.rb
      create    app/models/movie.rb
      invoke    rspec
      create    spec/models/movie_spec.rb
```

But when I run `rails g model movie showtime_date:date showtime_time:time`
I get

```
invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxx_create_movies.rb
      create    app/models/movie.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/movie_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/movies.yml
```

Is there a problem with my gem package? I am using Rails4 beta. Does this version have got error or something else?

The BDD for my app is like this `app/features/show_descripitons.feature`

```
Feature: Showtime Descriptions
    As a movie goer
    I want to see accurate and concise showtimes
    So that I can find movies that fit my schedule

    @wip
    Scenario: Show minutes for times ending with 00
        Given a movie
        When I set the showtime to "2013-05-04" at "2:15pm"
        Then the showtime description should be "June 04, 2013(2pm)"

    Scenario: Hide minutes for times ending with 00
        Given a movie
        When I set the showtime to "2013-05-04" at "2:00pm"
        Then the showtime description should be "June 04, 2013(2pm)"
```

and my `app/features/step_definition/showtime_descriptions.rb` is this

```
Given(/^a movie$/) do
    @movie = Movie.create!
end

When(/^I set the showtime to "(.*?)" at "(.*?)"$/) do |date, time|
    @movie.update_attribute(:showtime_date, Date.parse(date))
    @movie.update_attribute(:showtime_time, time)
end

Then(/^the showtime description should be "(.*?)"$/) do |showtime|
    @movie.showtime.showtime eq(showtime)
end
```

Comment: Did you run `rails generate rspec:install` at the begining?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I should put my this code in config/application.rb

```
    config.generators do |g|
       g.template_engine :erb
       g.test_framework  :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => false
       g.integration_tool :rspec, :fixture => true, :views => true
       g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/support/factories" 
     end
```

Comment: I first tried using the omit test unit option (-T, [--skip-test-unit]) that [Aaron K] suggested when creating my new rails project. That alone did not work until I added the above code to my application.rb.

Comment: This worked great except that g.fixture_replacement resulted in the message "factory_girl [not found]"  I use factory_girl for current specs so the Gem is installed and it's working; not sure why this resulted in an error message.

Comment: Reviewed this https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails/issues/53 and added factory_girl_rails to Gemfile

Answer (score 4):

Well, I also faced a similar problem with 4.1. But in the end, following ticket helped me to resolve the issue. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/439

In short, you have to make sure that `rspec-rails` is in the `development` group and not only in the `test` group. With that small change and `bundle install`, I got all the spec files generated automatically.

Comment: Or you could do `RAILS_ENV=test rails g model whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you added RSpec after you already created the rails project. You will need to remove the test unit generator reference. Make sure you have run `rails g rspec:install` and that the following is not in your `config/application.rb` (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow):

```
g.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: true
```

When creating a new rails project you can omit test unit with the `-T, [--skip-test-unit]` flag.

Comment: hey, as you have said. I follow it and once again create new one but the result is like this

rails g model movie showtime_date:date showtime_time:time
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20130607172805_create_movies.rb
      create    app/models/movie.rb

Comment: @AmritdeepDhungana did your run `rails g rspec:install`? If so what was the output?

Comment: the out was as follow

rails g rspec:install
      create  .rspec
      create  spec
      create  spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: Did you try running with bundler? `bundle exec rails g model movie name`?

Comment: I think the code will be like this for rspec 

g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true